# WinForms context menu really slow adding 150 Toolstrip Menu Items

Tags: vb.net, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I have this code that add items to a context menu's sub-menu:

```
 CTX_VALUE.Enabled = True
 CTX_VALUE.Visible = True
 CTX_VALUE.Text = "List Values"

 For k As Integer = 0 To CELL.VALUE_LIST.Count - 1
     CTX_VALUE.DropDownItems.Add(CELL.VALUE_LIST(k))
 Next k
```

Where `CTX_VALUE` is a `ToolStripMenuItem`

and `CELL.VALUE_LIST` is an `ArrayList` (yeah, old code!) of `ToolStripMenuItems`

When it comes to add about 150 items, it becomes really slow, about 2.5 seconds.

Visibility before adding doesn't matter, i tried moving it after.
BTW, note that the context menu is **not** on screen when adding items!

I also tried **suspending layout** of `CTX_VALUE` before adding. No luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should add these using  `CTX_VALUE.DropDownItems.AddRange()` method

Answer (score 1):

Before the ***add items*** loop I used both

ts_filter.DropDown.SuspendDrawing (see addendum note below)

and

ts_filter.DropDown.SuspendLayout

After the loop I used the corresponding resume methods.
This made a huge difference to my program moving it from unworkable to instant.

Addendum:-
The resumedrawing (alone) was preventing my custom textbox (inherited from toolstriptextboxfrom) from showing.  I found the suspendlayout and resumelayout to be ok alone though and it kept the speed up.

Comment: Quote: *the context menu is not on screen*.

Comment: Good point - it wasn't in my instance either as I was still building it in memory but having checked my code I accept that the root was and so likely triggering the display events as it built.  I am leaving the above in though because this is where I landed on searching as to why adding ToolstripItems was so very slow and maybe the original question might lead people to think it doesn;t matter.